# Passivist method of defense

Tags: clash-of-clans

In an effort to keep my trophy count low, I haven't yet attack another player in the week or so since I started playing CoC. So far, I've only been attacked once even though my resources usually hover around 50k (TH4). My idea is that, even though the prospective benefit from attacking me is relatively high, the prospects of actually getting a significant amount of my resources are very low for the people matched against me given the trophy based match maker.

What I've thought of so far:

**Pros**

- Low level potential attackers that aren't likely to even attempt an attack
- Not getting farmed/keeping more of my resources

**Cons**

- Not getting to farm others
- When I do start to attack others, on average, they will have a much lower TH level than me and I won't get to keep much of what I take until I get enough trophies to get matched with equal opponents

Are there any pros or cons to this trade off I'm not considering? While this is obviously somewhat opinionated, is the strategy worth using?

Comment: "In an effort to keep my trophy count low, I haven't yet attack another player". Mate, you can lose on purpose to keep your trophies low.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest drawback is **low resource income**. Clash of Clans was designed to make it so that those who attack and gather resources are going to progress faster than those who play it safe.

At Town Hall 4, here are the relevant statistics:

- Max number of collectors: 4 of each type.
- Max storage in each collector: 50,000 (will max out after ~26 hours)
- Collection rate for each collector: 1,900/hr

This means that for each gold and elixer, you can generate at most 7,600 per hour if you have all collectors fully upgraded.

Looking back at when I played TH4, I could get easily 3-4x that in a single attack on another player. Even with basic units, 100k+/hr was easy to do. So by not attacking, you are effectively limiting your income severely. This means that you're going to upgrade slower than those at your level who *are* attacking other players.

Even if you're constantly keeping your builders busy, those extra resources are good for upgrading your walls especially since you can now upgrade with either gold *or* elixer.

Comment: Are there any resources you know of that will give me a good idea of which goblin levels someone should be able to beat at each TH level? I'd like to at least make sure I'm good at fighting before starting to use PvP. And I should say, my laboratory and builders are always busy, so I don't see how upping my resource income will help me progress faster, other than upgrading fences.

Comment: There's going to be times where there's no point to hoarding resources (ie, you have too much income and nothing to spend it on) - This is normal. As long as you are able to keep your builders and laboratory busy, and bring enough in to upgrade your walls as well, then there's no point in getting too many resources otherwise. As far as single-player campaign, I'm not sure. Only the last few levels are worth the resource income, and those I wouldn't bother with until TH8/TH9.